# BeautifulSoup extract all/multiple tables from class/page

Tags: html, beautifulsoup

I have the problem that I want to extract all of the "Zutaten" from the table on from this [page](https://www.chefkoch.de/rezepte/2557531400251892/Rhabarber-Streusel-Kuchen.html). I tried several code examples but they either threw an Error about objects and they're attributes or they just gave me the first table. I hope you can help me.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.chefkoch.de/rezepte/2557531400251892/Rhabarber-Streusel-Kuchen.html'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

all_data = []
for tag in soup.select('.recipe-ingredients h3, .recipe-ingredients tr:not(:has(th))'):
    if tag.name == 'h3':
        all_data.append([tag.get_text(strip=True)])
    else:
        all_data.append([re.sub(r'\s{2,}', ' ', td.get_text(strip=True)) for td in tag.select('td')])

# print data to screen:
from pprint import pprint
pprint(all_data)

# save data to csv
import csv
with open('data.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for row in all_data:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Prints:

```
[['700 g', 'Rhabarber'],
 ['Für die Streusel:'],
 ['100 g', 'Butter, flüssig'],
 ['200 g', 'Mehl'],
 ['1 Prise(n)', 'Salz'],
 ['60 g', 'Puderzucker'],
 ['1 Pck.', 'Vanillezucker'],
 ['Für den Teig:'],
 ['225 g', 'Butter, weiche'],
 ['225 g', 'Zucker'],
 ['1 Prise(n)', 'Salz'],
 ['3', 'Ei(er), Größe M'],
 ['275 g', 'Mehl'],
 ['2 TL, gestr.', 'Backpulver'],
 ['150 g', 'Naturjoghurt']]
```

and saves `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

Comment: Thank you it works perfectly. But can you maybe explain what the line ".recipe-ingredients tr:not(:has(th))" selects and what "all_data.append([re.sub(r'\s{2,}', ' ', td.get_text(strip=True)) for td in tag.select('td')])" adds to all_data?

Comment: @Frederick `soup.select('.recipe-ingredients h3, .recipe-ingredients tr:not(:has(th))'):` is using CSS selector. It means that it selects all `<h3>` tags under tags with class `recipe-ingredients` and all `<tr>` tags that don't have `<tr>` tags inside. The `re.sub(r'\s{2,}', ' ', ...` just cleans the text from extra spaces.

Comment: Thank you for your fast and friendly help. :D